# How to pass value to viewpager fragment from other activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

Here let me explain my requirement i have two tabs of viewpager namely task and calls .  There is one button in task fragment when user clicks that it will go to new activity from there users will enter the values in edittext then the values from this activity need to populate listview in task fragment of that viewpager how can i do this.  So far what i have tried is:

THis is my Main activity:

```
package servicefiirst.precision.activitiestabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        //  Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        // Intent intent=getIntent();
        //   ActivityView activityView=(ActivityView)intent.getSerializableExtra("yog");
        //     intent.putExtra("yogs",activityView);
        // Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        // bundle.putSerializable("yogs",activityView);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String yogan = bundle.getString("yog");
            String yogans = bundle.getString("yogs");
            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("yoges", yogan);
            bundle.putString("yogesh", yogans);
            Task task = new Task();
            task.setArguments(bundle1);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                            Task task=new Task();
                            return task;

                    case 1:
                            Calls calls=new Calls();
                            return calls;

                }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
           switch (position){
               case 0:
                   return "Task";
               case 1:
                   return "Call";

            }
        return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

This is Task fragment in viewpager where listview is there:

```
package servicefiirst.precision.activitiestabs;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Task extends Fragment
{
    List<ActivityView>activityViews;
    ActivityView activityView=new ActivityView();
    ActivityListAdapter activityListAdapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.yog,container,false);
        ListView listview=(ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        if (activityViews == null)
        {
            activityViews = new ArrayList<ActivityView>();

        }
        if(getArguments()!=null) {
            getArguments().getSerializable("yog");
        }
        activityViews.add(activityView);
            activityListAdapter = new ActivityListAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.listView, activityViews);
            listview.setAdapter(activityListAdapter);
            activityListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Button btn=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



        return rootview;
    }

    }
```

This is detail activity where data go to populate listview in task fragment:

```
package servicefiirst.precision.activitiestabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityView activityView = new ActivityView();
    // public static String endpoint;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.yog, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activityView.setDescription(editText.getText().toString());
                activityView.setStatus(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
              //  Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
               // bundle.putSerializable("yog", activityView);
                Task task=new Task();
                //task.setArguments(bundle);
                android.support.v4.app. FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.  FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.container,task,"");
                ft.commit();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

how to navigate data from other activity to fragment of viewpager of other acitivity?  can anybody help me

Comment: Start activity with startActivityForResult() method. you can use onActivityResult() method in your taskfragment to retrieve data from Activity.

Comment: can you  please just explain me in detail @Sudheer

Answer (score 0):

Start the activity from task fragment using

```
startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

method, it will let fragment to receive result data from the activity. In new Activity when button is pressed to populate values save the values to a intent so you can send that intent to fragment by using

```
setResult(intent) // setResult has other overloaded methods pick them to your requirement
```

method of Activity class in your button onClickListener onClick() method.

```
    Ex : onClick() {
        intent.putString("name", editText.getText());
        setResult(intent); // setting the intent as result to receive at fragment
        this.finish(); // To finish the activity
 }
```

When activity gets finished(when you call finish() or press back button)

```
onActivityResult(intent)
```

method of Fragment which started the activity will be automatically called. you can use this method to retrieve the intent which contained the populated data.

Answer (score 0):

Please use static variable to save the value from your activity  and then resuse it in task fragment by calling the task fragment of viewpager activity , i guess it would helps you..!!

Comment: in my case am passing objects

Comment: In that case you interface callback instead

Comment: can you share some snippet